# Android Text To Speech Repeat Functionality

Tags: android

Have two buttons. Start and Repeat. On start TTS(Text To Speech) should start reading text from **textview**(t1). While reading text if I clicked repeat **button** TTS should keep repeating reading text(once it finished reading (t1) completely) till I clicked stop **button**. (Just Like Music Player)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got Solution by calling method onUtteranceCompleted.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener, TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener {
...
}

private void speak(String text) {
    if (text != null) {
        HashMap<String, String> myHashAlarm = new HashMap<String, String>();

String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM));
        myHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "SOME MESSAGE");
        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, myHashAlarm);

    }
}


@Override
    public void onUtteranceCompleted(String s) {
             if(repateOn) {
              // call speak method      
              speak(textString);
             }
        }
```

Thanks.